# Access in memory dbcontext in integration test

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, integration-testing

How can I access the dbcontext of an in memory database inside an integration test?

I have followed the code here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-2.2#customize-webapplicationfactory

and have a similar test to:

```
public class IndexPageTests : 
    IClassFixture<CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup>>
{
    private readonly HttpClient _client;
    private readonly CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> 
        _factory;

    public IndexPageTests(
        CustomWebApplicationFactory<RazorPagesProject.Startup> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
        _client = factory.CreateClient(new WebApplicationFactoryClientOptions
            {
                AllowAutoRedirect = false
            });
    }
```

In this IndexPageTests is it possible to access the in-memory dbcontext?

I have tried

```
 using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext(???))
```

I need to access data from tables i had previously seeded from CustomWebApplicationFactory

but not sure what to put for the options

Comment: You would have to resolve it via the host's services provider. `factory.Server.Host.Services.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>()`

Comment: @Nkosi, this gives error : Cannot resolve scoped service 'ApplicationDbContext' from root provider.

Comment: @Nikosi, thanks you pointed me in the right direction... had to create scope first _factory.Server.Host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();

Comment: Glad to help. You should add it as a self answer so that others can benefit.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Thanks to Nikosi, this is the way I managed to get the dbcontext

```
var scopeFactory = _factory.Server.Host.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>();
using (var scope = scopeFactory.CreateScope())
{
   var context = scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext>();
}
```

Comment: Add the using `using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;` so you get the `GetService<T>` and `GetRequiredService<T>` methods

Comment: I had to use `_factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory>()` in .NET 6.

Answer (score 3):

The below worked with me as it didn't throw an exception:

```
var scope = factory.Services.GetService<IServiceScopeFactory().CreateScope();
var context =  scope.ServiceProvider.GetService<ApplicationDbContext();
```

Ref. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/14424

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).